# How can a level 11 druid have a Dire Tortoise as an animal companion?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I do not understand how a level 11 druid by RAW can have a Dire Tortoise (from sandstorm) as an animal companion.

Comment: Could... you discuss the *reasons* why you're asking this question? Are you trying to find out how, are you trying to tell one of your players that they can't have it?

Comment: Welcome to RPG SE, Conor. I have changed your question title to reflect the question you are asking, but I still don't fully understand the intent of your question. From the way you are asking, I can infer at least three different questions: 1. A player in your group has a Dire Tortoise (or some Guide said Dire Tortoises make awesome ACs), and you want to know how that's possible by RAW. 2. You'd like to have a Dire Tortoise Animal Companion, and want to know how to actually get one. 3. You want to know how you can get Dire Tortoise AC outside of it's natural environment.

Answer (score 15):

As per the Wasteland animal companions sidebar (p48):

> Any of the listed animals are appropriate for a *wasteland* druid to select as an animal companion ... druids of sufficiently high level can choose the following animal companions ... Level 10 ... Dire Tortoise

Looking at the [handbook](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=1354.msg35416#msg35416), this creature is certainly accepted as the best creature to choose at this level. So, until level 14, at which point they get a Horrid Dire Tortoise this choice is quite significant. The only tradeoff is that they do need to be a wasteland druid (with the appropriate alternate class features.) This feature is a nice cherry on the rather remarkable sundae (7 flavours and counting) that comprises the 3.5 Druid. Take heart: they could be riding an armored and buffed Allosaurus instead.

(dire) [Ice cream turtle](http://www.bluebunny.com/Recipes/d/Blue_Bunny_Ice_Cream_Turtle_Sundae) provided for reference:

[image]

Comment: Oh my goodness, I want to eat that dire turtle!